# SendRedirect "preventing resubmission" guaranteed?

Tags: java, servlets

Hi I'm new to server side programming (java) and was reading the difference between SendRedirect vs. Forward. 
From [Post-redirect-get pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) it explains that this will prevent resubmitting the modification through hitting the refresh button. But what if the server side postprocessing is heavy, and during the server processing the post and BEFORE it send back a 3xx redirect, a user refresh the page? How would server know to ignore the second incoming request in a row?

Answer (score 0):

I get your point, in fact PRG guarantees to prevent double POST submissions including back button *only if a previous redirect was done*, so the browser now can send a GET request.

> **But what happens if a long process is running before making that redirect??**

There are two known ways for me to handle this situations:

- It's logical that PGR objective won't be satisfied if you have a long-time process to do before redirect; so if someone is into this kind of trouble, `then long-time process should be consider to run in separate thread` then you can simply send your redirect to a page where you can show progress to user (optional), this resembles Ajax.
- This one i haven't tried it but it's really logical **`Synchronization Token pattern`**, so it's basically based on setting a hidden token in your page, then when a POST request is sent to the server you will increment by any number that token and `store it into session`, so next time user clicks submit button or refresh page you can `compare the token` that gets settled every time your page comes up with the one stored in session, this is an alternative way you can avoid processing same request associated to the same user over and over.

I give you this link if you want to check more about it http://www.deepakgaikwad.net/index.php/2009/03/19/post-redirect-get-design-pattern.html

Hope it's useful...